# Magento Indexer Not Adding Attribute to flat table in custom attribute

Tags: magento-1, product-attribute, indexing, flat-catalog

Magento Not adding custom Attribute to flat table.....
I have a market place extension...which have some attribute but some attributes not adding to flat table...due to my extension not working....

attribute setting is...

```
$catalogEavSetup->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'approval', array(
    'group' => 'General',
    'sort_order' => 21,
    'type' => 'int',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'Approval',
    'note' => '',
    'input' => 'select',
    'class' => '',
    'source' => 'vendorsproduct/source_approval',
    'global' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => false,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '1',
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'unique' => false,
    'is_configurable' => false,
    'used_for_promo_rules' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing'  => true,
));
```

whole setting is correct..but due to mysql limit 65536...some attributes is not adding to flat tables...
I need to know that how to add these attribute in flat tables...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to enable `visible_on_front` to push into the Catalog Flat tables. Category flat tables are affected by `used_in_product_listing`.

As for the limit in MySQL I believe that is a separate question and should be migrated out as a separate Q&A.

Comment: its not coming in flat table....is there any good way to indexing or getting value of attribute

Comment: Totally wrong. You only need to enable "used_in_product_listing" to make it appear on catalog_product_flat table.

Comment: Agreed with @KingshukDeb i just tested and enabling "used_in_product_listing" will make the attribute show in catalog_product_flat table

Comment: I still have the same problem. The attribute is working fine, products do have values, a lot actually. But though, no data in the flat catalog :(

Comment: If you are in the same case than @DeepakRai, you have defined your own source model. If so, you need to implement 2 methods to add the attribute is flat table. I added an answer to explain how.

Comment: @philwinkle you are right we need to set both visibility and used_in_product_listing_page

Answer (score 5):

Another way to add attributes to flat tables is to set them in your [`config.xml`](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml#L751-L774) frontend section ...

```
<product>
    <collection>
        <attributes>
            <attribute_code/>
        </attributes>
    </collection>
</product>
```

Answer (score 5):

As already told in other answers, you need `used_in_product_listing` to be set to `1`.

But as you defined a source model (`'source' => 'vendorsproduct/source_approval',`), you may need an extra step :

In your source model, you most probably extended `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract` and already implemented `getAllOptions`.

But you also need to implements two more methods :

- `getFlatColums` (this is not a typo, there is no "n")
- `getFlatUpdateSelect`

To implement them, take example from the Magento native source model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Boolean`.

Here is an example of what you should end up with :

```
class Vendor_Products_Model_Source_Approval
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Option values
     */
    const VALUE_APPROVED = 1;
    const VALUE_NOT_APPROVED = 0;


    /**
     * Retrieve all options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_options)) {
            $this->_options = array(
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('vendorsproduct')->__('Yes'),
                    'value' => self::VALUE_APPROVED
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('vendorsproduct')->__('No'),
                    'value' => self::VALUE_NOT_APPROVED
                ),
            );
        }
        return $this->_options;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $_options = array();
        foreach ($this->getAllOptions() as $option) {
            $_options[$option['value']] = $option['label'];
        }
        return $_options;
    }

    /**
     * Get a text for option value
     *
     * @param string|integer $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionText($value)
    {
        $options = $this->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            if ($option['value'] == $value) {
                return $option['label'];
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve flat column definition
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFlatColums()
    {
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttribute()->getAttributeCode();
        $column = array(
            'unsigned'  => false,
            'default'   => null,
            'extra'     => null
        );

        if (Mage::helper('core')->useDbCompatibleMode()) {
            $column['type']     = 'tinyint(1)';
            $column['is_null']  = true;
        } else {
            $column['type']     = Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_SMALLINT;
            $column['length']   = 1;
            $column['nullable'] = true;
            $column['comment']  = $attributeCode . ' column';
        }

        return array($attributeCode => $column);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Select For Flat Attribute update
     *
     * @param int $store
     * @return Varien_Db_Select|null
     */
    public function getFlatUpdateSelect($store)
    {
        return Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')
            ->getFlatUpdateSelect($this->getAttribute(), $store);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cladiuss, I still have the same problem. I follow you added 2 function, it's will add to table, but when i go to category on frontend, it show bug " Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.custom_attribute' in 'where clause' ". i don't use it on where clause

Comment: SELECT FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 100) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN .....

Comment: Amazing! Saved my day. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For me it was enough to set only "used_in_product_listing" => true

```
'attribute_code' => array(
    'type'                          => 'int',
    'input'                         => 'select',
    'global'                        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    'required'                      => 0,
    'is_configurable'               => 0,
    'visible_in_advanced_search'    => 0,
    'comparable'                    => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => 0,
    'user_defined'                  => 1,
    'used_in_product_listing'       => 1,
    'source'                        => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
)
```

and run catalog_product_flat reindex to get product attribute in flat table:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindex catalog_product_flat
```

Comment: Does it also work on core Magento attributes (```quantity_and_stock_status``` specifically)?

Comment: No. Stock is a separate entity in Magento and it is not included into flat tables of catalog_product_flat.
So you need to use separate Magento model to get qty.