# Problem after activating Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product

Tags: magento-1.8, category, frontend, custom

I've activated the following two features for speeding up my site
 Use Flat Catalog Category
 Use Flat Catalog Product
then re-indexing But then some parts of my site will not show up correctly.
for example Menus are displayed while submenues are not displayed or in some pages do not show the menu images.

Comment: Do you mean that some of your custom attributes are not rendered on frontend?

Comment: yes,some of my custom attributes are not rendered on frontend

Comment: for example Menus are displayed while submenues are not displayed or in some pages do not show the menu images.

Comment: Check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80722/magento-indexer-not-adding-attribute-to-flat-table-in-custom-attribute for custom attributes

Comment: I tried, but i got no results !!!